# Verb form before そうです

Tags: grammar, verbs

> 今、新しい仕事を探しているみたいですよ。奥さんとも離婚**する**そうですよ。

I'd say `離婚しているそうですよ`. Why is the form する　used here?

If he has already got divorced, perhaps, it's better to say `離婚したそうですよ`. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because he has not divorced his wife yet. ～するそうです means "I hear (It is said) that someone will do something". ～したそうです means "I hear (It is said) that someone did something".

Of course, 離婚したそうですよ makes sense.

Comment: What if he’s in the process of getting divorced?

Comment: @Enguroo I say 彼は、離婚協議中だ.